# Zend_Pdf table?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Is it possible to create a table in Zend_Pdf? If yes, could you give me some code snippet?

I've tried searching documentation and devzone but I couldn't find anything about adding tables to pdf.

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible. Take a look at fpdf.

http://www.fpdf.org/

Comment: Thanks, after all I "created" tables by drawing lines and rectangles with Zend_Pdf, it was a little more difficult but it worked (fpdf can create tables but there are problems when you need to wrap a text inside a cell).

Answer (score 1):

Yea you have to manually draw the lines. Something to get you started:

```
$pdf->pages[0]
->setStyle($h3)
->drawLine(73, 244, 512, 244)   // HEAD Bottom
->drawLine(73, 244, 73, 166)    // MOST Left
->drawLine(512, 244, 512, 166)  // MOST Right
->drawLine(73, 166, 512, 166)       // MOST Bottom
->drawLine(225, 244, 225, 166)      // MOST Left
->setStyle($h2)
->drawText('Analytics Site', 73, 252)   // Table Headers
->setStyle($h3)
->drawText('Page Views', 80, 225)           // Table Headers (402) - 27
->drawText('Bounce Rate', 80, 200)      // Table Headers
->drawText('Avg. Time On Site', 80, 174)    // Table Headers
->drawLine(73, 192, 512, 192)   // Bottom
->drawLine(73, 218, 512, 218)   // Bottom
->drawText($site_metrics[0]->{"ga:pageviews"}, 235, 225)
->drawText(sprintf('%1.02f%%', $site_metrics[0]->{"ga:visitBounceRate"}), 235, 200)
->drawText($avg_time, 235, 174);
```

that snippet was for a pdf for monthly analytics reports on a site i did.

Comment: just realized im a month or two late =/ hopefully someone finds it useful regardless

Answer (score 1):

Try [Zend_Pdf_Table](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zendpdftable/)  (http://sourceforge.net/projects/zendpdftable/)

It's based on ZF1, handles rows, columns, headers, does text wrapping, renders multi-page tables, supports cell padding and left/right/center alignment. It can be quirky at times, but does its job.